# Access OpenSSH on guest OS from another?

Tags: ssh, sftp

I have Ubuntu on my vbox running OpenSSH . How to access it from another guest OS that runs Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to get ssh access to the ubuntu box, or [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) to get sshfs access to it.

Download [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and tell it the Ubuntu's IP address.

Comment: Before I could access it from my host os I had to map guest port 22 to my 2222, but how to do that on guest Windows 7?

Comment: There should be a port setting in the putty program you can change to 2222

Comment: I'd recommend using bridged networking it will put both guests on the same subnet as your host